# Eliminating code duplication in a single file

Tags: refactoring, code-duplication

Sadly, a project that I have been working on lately has a large amount of copy-and-paste code, even within single files.  Are there any tools or techniques that can detect duplication or near-duplication within a single file?  I have Beyond Compare 3 and it works well for comparing separate files, but I am at a loss for comparing single files.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

Thanks for all the great tools!  I'll definitely check them out.

This project is an ASP.NET/C# project, but I work with a variety of languages including Java; I'm interested in what tools are best (**for any language**) to remove duplication.

Comment: The solutions are completely different for different languages. Tagging for ASP.NET/C#.

Comment: Correct, but I would like to know the best tools for the most popular languages (because I work with several languages at a time).  Thanks though.

Comment: The CloneDR solution is the *same* for many languages.  CloneDR handles C#, Java, HTML and JavaScript, which I think covers the OP's "ASP.NET" situation pretty well.

Comment: Other keywords to look for: copy-paste detection, similarity recognition. You can give [tag:pmd] a try

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Eclipse, you can use the copy paste detector (CPD) https://olex.openlogic.com/packages/cpd.

Answer (score 1):

See [SD CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone), a tool for detecting copy-paste-edit code within and across multiple files.  It detects exact copyies, copies that have been reformatted, and near-miss copies with different identifiers, literals, and even different seqeunces of statements.

The CloneDR handles many languages, including Java (1.4,1.5,1.6) and C# especially up to C#4.0.  You can see sample clone detection reports at the website, also including one for C#.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what language you are using, which is going to affect what tools you can use.

For Python there is [CloneDigger](http://clonedigger.sourceforge.net/).  It also supports Java but I have not tried that.  It can find code duplication both with a single file and between files, and gives you the result as a diff-like report in HTML.

Answer (score 0):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) does this automagically - it suggests when it thinks code should be extracted into a method, and will do the extraction for you

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PMD](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd/4.2.5/) , once you have configured it (which is tad simple) you can run its [copy paste detector](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html) to find duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

One with some Office skills can do following sequence in 1 minute:

- use ordinary formatter to unify the code style, preferably without line wrapping
- feed the code text into Microsoft Excel as a single column
- search and replace all dual spaces with single one and do other replacements
- sort column

At this point the keywords for duplicates will be already well detected. But to go further

- add comparator formula to 2nd column and counter to 3rd
- copy and paste values again, sort and see the most repetitive lines

Answer (score 0):

There is an analysis tool, called [Simian](http://www.redhillconsulting.com.au/products/simian/), which I haven't yet tried. Supposedly it can be run on any kind of text and point out duplicated items. It can be used via a command line interface.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Another option similar to those above, but with a different tool chain: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jscpd